# Insert Java variable using Java in SQL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I was trying to do:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO CURRENT_WEATHER_US VALUES("+city_code+",   
"+object.city+","+object.region+","+object.country+","+object.wind_chill+",  
"+object.wind_direction+", "+object.wind_speed+","+object.humidity+","+object.visibility+", 
"+object.pressure+","+object.rising+",  
"+object.sunrise+","+object.sunset+","+object.textual_description+",  
"+object.condition_code+","+object.temp+","+object.for_temp_high+",  
"+object.for_temp_low+","+object.for_description+","+object.forecast_code+")";   

  stmt.execute(sql);
```

Error is  missing comma

Please Help

Comment: This is the worst possible way to work with SQL statements in Java.  See BalusC's answer for the right way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not really the way you're supposed to construct and execute a SQL INSERT query with variables. This is not only prone to [SQL injection attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), but it is also pretty .. cumbersome ;) Possibly a value contained a singlequote and caused your query to be syntactically invalid.

Just do not string-concatenate variables into a SQL string. Instead, use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) ([tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)) in combination with `?` as placeholder for the variable in the SQL string. This way you can nicely put fullworthy Java objects (including `Date` and `InputStream`!) in a SQL statement by value index without worrying about characters in strings which may syntactically break the SQL query (and thus also induce SQL injection risks).

Here's a kickoff example based on your original SQL query:

```
private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO CURRENT_WEATHER_US"
    + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

public void create(String cityCode, Weather weather) throws SQLException {
    try (
        Connection connection = database.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
    ) {
        statement.setString(1, cityCode);
        statement.setString(2, weather.getCity());
        statement.setString(3, weather.getRegion());
        // ...
        statement.setString(20, weather.getForecastCode());
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

To learn more about using *basic JDBC* the proper way, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using PrepairedStatements instead of building Strings.  They are quicker and take care of many pitfalls related to quoting and escaping values.

Answer (score 0):

Like all the others say, you really should convert it to use PreparedStatements for a number of reasons.  You are most likely getting the error (you didn't post the exact ORA error) because you passing in String type values, but you didn't wrap them in single quotes in your hard coded query.

If textual_description and for_description where the only String type columns in your query, then your query would need to look like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO CURRENT_WEATHER_US VALUES( " +
    city_code + ", " +
    object.city + ", " +
    object.region + ", " +
    object.country + ", " +
    object.wind_chill  + ", " +
    object.wind_direction + ", " +
    object.wind_speed + ", " +
    object.humidity + ", " +
    object.visibility + ", " +
    object.pressure + ", " +
    object.rising + ", " +
    object.sunrise + ", " +
    object.sunset + ", " +
    "'" + object.textual_description + "', " +
    object.condition_code + ", " +
    object.temp + ", " +
    object.for_temp_high + ", " +
    object.for_temp_low + ", " +
    "'" + object.for_description + "', " +
    object.forecast_code + 
    " )";   

stmt.execute(sql);
```

Notice the single quotes surrounding those values now.

Comment: And although not as bad as opening oneself to sql injection, building strings that way is not the preferred way ;-) Using for example a StringBuilder is way more efficient.